# can i use mailto in facebook post?

Tags: html, facebook

I need to put html tag in facebook user wall post.can i put below code in facebook post?

```
<a href="mailto:test@example.com">test@example.com</a>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: According to [this question][1] on Webapps.Stackexchange.com, it can't be done.


  [1]: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/is-it-possible-to-include-a-hyperlink-in-a-facebook-wall-post

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, since the <> characters are converted into html value & l t ; and  & g t ;  for security reasons. Otherwise anyone could make code injection (javascript, php, asp, etc..)